# set value's in img tag in php

Tags: php, image, kohana, kohana-3

I am trying to assign the dynamic path of the image using php.

While trying to echo the path using

```
echo '<img src="'.$guild_image_path.'"/>';
```

I am getting the correct path.

But if i apply the same in my application i am not getting the image path.

Please refer my code below,

```
printf( '<span class="byline"><span class="rounded_image"><a  href="%4$s" rel="author"><?php echo '<img src="'.$guild_image_path.'"/>'; ?>%5$s</a></span></span>',  
                esc_url( get_permalink() ),
        esc_attr( get_the_date( 'c' ) ),
        esc_html( get_the_date() ),
        esc_url( get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ) ),
        get_the_author()
    );
```

Please help me to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try debug using error_log or echo before `printf()` to make sure you are getting the value in the variable `$guild_image_path`.

```
error_log('image path'.$guild_image_path);
```

or

```
echo $guild_image_path;
```

Answer (score 1):

Why you use echo in printf?
Second printf is arleady PHP so you dont need to open php tags again.

```
printf( '<span class="byline"><span class="rounded_image"><a  href="%4$s" rel="author"><img src="'.$guild_image_path.'"/>%5$s</a></span></span>',  
            esc_url( get_permalink() ),
    esc_attr( get_the_date( 'c' ) ),
    esc_html( get_the_date() ),
    esc_url( get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ) ),
    get_the_author()
);
```

Read more about printf: http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.printf.php